# Python - Only reading last line of file in specific circumstance

Tags: python, json, for-loop, twitter, readline

I'm trying to process some tweets using Python, and I'm trying to do a word count of the most popular words contained in 7 different tweets. I have my file set up, each tweet is a JSON object on its own line, and when I try to print out each tweet using the following, it works perfectly:

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line) # load it as Python dict
    print(json.dumps(tweet, indent=4))
```

However, when I am trying to do something similar in my word count, it either reads the last line of the file 7 times, or just the last line of the file once. I am using the following code, removing stopwords from the results:

```
with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
count_all = Counter()
# Create a list with all the terms
terms_stop = [term for term in tokens if term not in stop]
for line in f:
    # Update the counter
    count_all.update(terms_stop)
# Print the first 5 most frequent words
print(count_all.most_common(5))
```

The above produces 5 random words from the last tweet, and the count of each one is at 7 - meaning that it essentially read the last tweet 7 times instead of reading each of the 7 tweets once.

The following code is meant to see which words are most commonly grouped together. It produces 5 randomly grouped words from the last tweet, with the count at just 1, which signifies that it only read the last tweet (once) and none of the other tweets.

```
with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
count_all = Counter()
# Create a list with all the terms
terms_stop = [term for term in tokens if term not in stop]
# Import Bigrams to group words together
terms_bigram = bigrams(terms_stop)
for line in f:
    # Update the counter
    count_all.update(terms_bigram)
# Print the first 5 most frequent words
print(count_all.most_common(5))
```

The format of my json file is as follows:

```
{"created_at":"Tue Oct 25 11:24:54 +0000 2016","id":4444444444,.....}
{"created_at":..... }
{etc}
```

Help would be most appreciated! Thanks very much in advance.

UPDATE:
Don't know how I missed it, but thanks for the help everyone! I forgot to include 'line' in my for loop. Here is the working code:

```
with open(fname, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
count_all = Counter()
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tokens = preprocess(tweet['text'])
    # Create a list with all the terms
    terms_stop = [term for term in tokens if term not in stop]
    # Update the counter
    count_all.update(terms_stop)
# Print the first 5 most frequent words
print(count_all.most_common(5))
```

I just had to combine the tokenizer with the word count.

Comment: Is your indentation correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I am missing something but you never use line in the for-loop:

```
for line in f:
    # Update the counter
    count_all.update(terms_bigram)
```

so you are just looping over the lines doing the same thing for each line.

Comment: Worked! Thankyou! I'll edit my original question with the working solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read the file:

```
with open(fname) as d:
    tweet = json.load(d)
```

If this dont work, post more info about the file data format.

New update:

```
with open(fname) as d:
    data = d.readlines()

tweet = [json.loads(x) for x in data]
```

This will give you a list of dictionaries (json format)

Comment: It gives an error - JSONDecodeError: Extra Data: line 2 column 1. I'll edit my original post regarding the file data format. Thanks for your help.